# Run Chrome by application with WebRTC

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-10, webrtc

I am working on a software that runs Chrome on a specific url which uses WebRTC, running manually like cmd or with the IDE works fine, Chrome asks for permission and everything works, but running by another compiled software like VBS(wscript or cscript), PB or NodeJS does not work, it still asks for permission, but even with everything allowed, camera and mic doesn't show.

This is what I run by cmd

`chrome.exe https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/` - Works

Running this line by some another executable, camera and mic doesn't work. I tried with another browsers, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge. But still doesn't work, Edge sometimes work but it's very unreliable, worked on 1 out of 3 computers I tried.

I think it has something to do on Windows blocking the devices but I don't know how to make it work

Thanks